# Deactivate wordpress plugin for a specific user role

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to deactivate the (TeraWallet) plugin for all user roles only allow the subscriber roles.

I'm using this code to deactivate the plugin for the customer role:

```
function desactivate_plugin_wallet()
{
    global $current_user;
    if (in_array('customer', $current_user->roles)) {
        deactivate_plugins('/woo-wallet/woo-wallet.php');
    } else {
        activate_plugins('/woo-wallet/woo-wallet.php');
    }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'desactivate_plugin_wallet');
```

And I applying the code to activate the theme dfunction.php file.

But the code not working.

Advance thank you to a great and senior developer to resolve the problem.

Comment: I don't know how to deactivate the plugin for all roles and activities for a specific role that's why I going to apply the code multiple time to deactivate the plugin for multiple user roles. 

if you have a good suggestion to do this an easy way please specify.

Comment: you can't do this to specific role but you can remove/hide plugin menu access from admin dashboard for particular user role

Comment: This is realy bad practice. Every time someone visit the admin will turn on or off the plugin. How a subscriber have more priviliges to access a plugin over administrator ? LIke a soldier to give orders to a captain...

Answer (score 0):

As I am testing from my end, It's working perfectly, My test code sample is:

```
function desactivate_plugin_wallet()
{
    $myplugin = 'woo-wallet/woo-wallet.php';

    if (current_user_can( 'administrator' )) {
        activate_plugins($myplugin);
    } else {
        deactivate_plugins($myplugin);
    }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'desactivate_plugin_wallet', 10, 2);
```

Comment: current_user_can is for capability use $user->role for access to user role.

Comment: Yes, you can verify from  - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/

Comment: But it will check the role only logging users not another user(who is not logging).

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('admin_init', 'my_filter_the_plugins');    
    function my_filter_the_plugins()
    {
        global $current_user;
        if (in_array('customer', $current_user->roles)) {
            deactivate_plugins( // deactivate for media_manager
                array(
                    '/woo-wallet/woo-wallet.php'
                ),
                true, // silent mode (no deactivation hooks fired)
                false // network wide
            );
        } else { // activate for those than can use it
            activate_plugins(
                array(
                    '/woo-wallet/woo-wallet.php'
                ),
                '', // redirect url, does not matter (default is '')
                false, // network wise
                true // silent mode (no activation hooks fired)
            );
        }
    }
```

Basically this happens:

For the customer user group the my_filter_the_plugins disables(silently) the plugin. We then need to reactivate the plugin(silently, again) for those that aren't in the customer user group.

Answer (score 0):

```
    add_filter('woo_wallet_form_cart_cashback_amount', 'woo_wallet_form_cart_cashback_amount_callback');
if (!function_exists('woo_wallet_form_cart_cashback_amount_callback')) {

    function woo_wallet_form_cart_cashback_amount_callback($cashback_amount) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        if (in_array('customer', (array) $user->roles)) {
            $cashback_amount = 0;
        }
        return $cashback_amount;
    }

}
```

This works for me.